# What is the .install4j/user directory good for when the installation is finished?

Tags: install4j

When I install my Java application on Windows using Install4J 9.0.5, I'll find a `.install4j\user` directory inside my installation directory. It contains several jar files and some other files used by the installer.

Do I still need this directory when the installation is finished? Maybe for uninstalling? And is there a built-in way for Install4J to delete this directory if it is not needed anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.install4j` directory contains the runtime for the generated launchers and for installer applications like the uninstaller.

You can only delete it if you only have external installers, no installer applications and if you do not use the install4j API from your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I really appreciate your support. I suppose this means deleting single files from this directory (as they might seem superfluous or unwanted) is not a good idea. Either delete the entire directory (given the conditions you mentioned in your answer) or leave the directory as it is.

Comment: Yes, that's correct